# Time, 3 clues only

Tags: riddle

> You will always find me in the past.
>   I can be created in the present
>   But the future can never taint me.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> History

You will always find me in the past.

> History is about the past things.

I can be created in the present

> You can create a history by doing something amazing.

But the future can never taint me.

> Well, it can't. It already happened.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

> Memory

You will always find me in the past.

> Memories are always in the past.

I can be created in the present

> Memories are created in the present..

But the future can never taint me. What am I?

> Future has not come yet and so cannot taint our memories or influence them.

Comment: No but good guess!

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> History.

I think this is a too common riddle.